# Android - Volley request works on simulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

This has been happening over the last couple days. We have a JsonObjectRequest:

```
public Map<String,String> loginUser(String uemail, String upassword, final AuthAsyncResponse callBack) {

    String url = "https://our.url/auth/signin";
    Map<String,String> userData = new HashMap<>();

    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParams.put("email", uemail);
    postParams.put("password", upassword);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new JSONObject(postParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        Log.d(TAG, "login status: " + response);

                        if (status.equals("Success")) {
                            // Work with data and set up userData object

                        } else {
                            //Log.d("Log", "onResponse: available" + status);
                            userData.put("status", status);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "login status: ", e);
                    }

                    if (null != callBack) callBack.processFinished(userData);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                }
            }
    )

    {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return userData;

}
```

If I run this on the simulator, everything works fine.

However as of a couple days ago, if I run it from the device, I get a Timeout error.

It appears that across the whole app, no JsonObjectRequests are working on the device, even though they were until last week. Even the app version that was already published can't load data anymore because of this.

I have tested the URL with Postman and it's working fine. We just don't know what is causing this error on the device.

UPDATE: After further testing we've found out that the issue is not Volley but the URL. If we substitute the URL for a different one, everything works. However this exact URL does work on both iOS and Postman and in the Android simulator. It's just when the request is made from an Android device that this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tested it with something else on the device, like a Web browser? Have you run a spike test trying some other HTTP client API, like OkHttp, to see if it exhibits the same problems (and perhaps has more information to tell you what is going wrong)?

Comment: Is `our.url` really a public service URL and not i.e. 192.168.0.x?